# Подключение БД к PostgreSQL(PGAdmin)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pgadmin4

Раньше не приходилось работать с бд, поэтому возникли некоторые трудности с отображением данных с БД. Есть некий проект(React, Express, Node.js и ProstgreSQL), после запуска, контент(не связанный с БД) отображается корректно, но сервер выдает ошибки 401 и 500(в консоли отображается как: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401/500).

Список БД, которые требуется подключить к PostgreSQL:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Конфигурация для работы с postgres:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего я скачал сам PostgreSQL, при загрузке порт по дэфолту указал 5432, после успешной загрузки зашел на страницу PGAdmin и на сервере PostgreSQL 12 установил данные подключение, которые совпадали бы с конфигами выше.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос, как подключить БД, которые отображены на 1 картинке к самому серверу PostgreSQL 12 или ошибка была совершена где-нибудь ранее?

Comment: Так требуется подключить эти базы, которые расположены где-то еще или создать их у себя?

Comment: вам нужно 1) создать свою базу данных (если это не делается в файле database.sql) 2) залить в свою базу данных данные из *.sql-файлов 3) создать пользователя от имени которого будет разрешён доступ к данных новой БД, чтение, модификация данных 4) в коде бэкенда прописать корректные параметры подключения. вы не знаете как это сделать так что варианта 3: разобраться, использовать ORM (typeorm, sequelize) или разделить этот вопрос на несколько вопросов, проходя каждый этап этого квеста

Comment: @nörbörnën , ок попытался это проделать через SQL Shell. По вашим пунктам, открываю консоль и заполняю выпадающие поля(Server, Database, Port, Username и Password), после чего идентичными данными заполняю конфиг на бэкенде(картинка 2), далее копирую содержимое database.sql и вставляю в консоль и через \d проверяю создались ли таблицы, таблицы действительно создались, как будто бы все верно или не совсем?

Comment: похоже на правду. если соблюдён пункт про создание новой БД то половина дела сделана

Comment: @nörbörnën , да, после ввода пароля, я создал БД(create database name) и подключился к ней через \с. Не подскажите пожалуйста следующие шаги?

Comment: создать пользователя, дать ему права или сделать овнером БД. разрешить ему подключение к БД (не знаю как это сделать через gui, обычно настраиваю через pg_hba.conf). в скрипт со второй картинки передать название новой БД, пользователя, его пароль и попробовать подключиться.

Comment: @nörbörnën , такс, создал нового пользователя и предоставил ему права суперпользователя и подключился, новосозданным пользователем, к БД(не забыв поменять данные конфига) и после этого просто запустить проект, верно?

Comment: подключился и проверь - напиши в js-коде `select` записей из какой-то таблицы